# VMware ESXi でゲストOSのセットアップ後も電源ONで繰り返しインストール画面が表示されてしまう

Tags: linux, vmware

VMware ESXi5.5を使用していましたが、最近6.7に乗り換えました。

そこで質問がございます。isoイメージをアップロードして、仮想マシンの作成方法まではわかるのですが、仮想マシンの
シャットダウン及び保存の仕方がわかりません。

まずパワーオンしてコンソールを開いてあとはいつも通りに作成するところまではわかるのですが、仮想マシンの電源を切るためにパワーオフしようとすると、「データが失われる可能性が…云々」とダイアログが表示されまして、無視して実行するとそれはそれでオフできた？のですが、次にパワーオンを押すと再びインストール画面から再生されてしまいます。

さっきまで色々設定も済ませていたマシンはどこへ？？という状態です。ちなみにOSはLinuxで、へんにUIからパワーオフの操作などせずに、「shutdown -h now」するとそれはそれで画面が黒いままずっと固まってしまいます。

何かESXiの初期設定自体に不備があると考えられますでしょうか。あるいは、どこかに作成～設定したマシンは保存されていて、次に起動するときのやり方が悪いとかでしょうか。

ググると、仮想マシンの作成からログインまでの流れを説明してくださっている記事はよく見かけるのですが、それ以降の操作が探せていない状態です。一度インストールを完了させてログインまでたどり着いたらISOイメージを取り外す必要があるのでしょうか（しかしどうやって…？）。

どなたか使い慣れている方がいらっしゃいましたら是非ご教授願います。

Comment: cubick様ありがとうございます。ひとまず強引にパワーオフし、「次回の起動時に強制的にBIOS画面～」に再びチェックを入れ順序を入れ替えることでマシンの保存に成功しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware固有の問題ではなく、物理的なPCを含めてBIOSには「起動順位」という設定項目があり、ハードディスクやCD/DVDドライブなどをどの順番でOSが入っているか探しにいくかを設定できます。

ハードディスクがまだ空の状態ならCDから起動してOSをインストールする必要がありますが、いったんOSをインストールしたなら今度はハードディスクを優先して起動しなければいけません。

しかし、CDドライブにインストールメディアが残った状態で、かつCDドライブの優先順位が高いままだと電源を入れるたびにOSインストールの画面が表示されることになります。

仮想マシンの構成(設定)を変更してインストールメディアを取り出しておくか、BIOSの画面を呼び出してハードディスクの起動順を1番に変更してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速チャレンジしております。現在まだコンソールが立ち上がっている状態なのですが、ひとますパワーオフをしてコンソールを閉じるべきでしょうか？

Comment: 仮想マシンの設定変更は、基本的に電源オフの状態でないとできないはずです。